# Layout of a ContiguousIterator: list of member functions?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

For a class of my own, I need to write an iterator class from scratch (without using std::iterator) (it will be a ContiguousIterator). I am searching for the list of required members and their signature, because I have no idea of all functions such an iterator should provide to be compliant with the standard library.

Where could I find an exhaustive list of these members and their signature?

Comment: The standard doesn't prescribe specific methods an iterator class should have. It specifies expressions involving an iterator that have to be valid and exhibit prescribed semantics. See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator . It's up to the implementor to choose how to make those expressions work out.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3884.pdf..i tried writing one a while back for a fenwick tree based on this..never completed it.